# Add text inside Button drawable in Android

Tags: android, xml, xamarin

I've got Android project in Xamarin. What I need to do is to add text inside image (green dot) placed in Button.

As you see I am adding green dot as drawable. So maybe I should make custom drawable which will be combined TextView and Image?

This is how it looks now / what I am trying to achieve:

[image]

## Button XML

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_synchronize"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/button_action"
        android:minHeight="60dp"
        android:maxHeight="60dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="60dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="Synkronisering"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_green_dot"
        android:drawablePadding="3dp"
        android:gravity="center" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

## Selector XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
<layer-list>
<item>
<shape>
<solid android:color="@color/main_orange_color" />
<stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@color/main_grey_color" />
<corners android:radius="4dp" />
<padding android:left="3dp" android:top="3dp" android:right="3dp" android:bottom="3dp" />
</shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
</item>
</selector>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can start with a `FrameLayout` with width and height both set to `wrap_content`. Then, add the `Button` as the view in the bottom. Add the `TextView` with appropriate styles applied. Change its `layout_gravity` appropriately.

For more, please have a look at: http://blog.neteril.org/blog/2013/10/10/framelayout-your-best-ui-friend/

> The secret of FrameLayout is how it layouts its children. Although
>   normally designed to contain one item, it will happily stack up other
>   element on top of each other. Thus FrameLayout is essentially a way to
>   manipulate the Z-order of views on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use `Button`. You can use any of `RelativeLayout`, `LinearLayout`, `FrameLayout` etc. and their combinations. When you assign an `OnClickListener` to them, they will act as a button already. So, let you `Button` be a `Layout`.